# Notepad ++ clone each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file that includes such lines

```
111
112
113
```

I want to clone the lines and add a seperator between the numbers. Output should be as the following

```
111#111
112#112
113#113
```

How can I do it with notepadd++ by using regex replace

Comment: Glad you found the solution yourself! Instead of editing the solution into your question it would be better (for future visitors) when you post your solution as an answer. It is perfectly valid to post an answer to your own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `(.+)`

Replace `\1#\1`

This will work